# Statements are not getting committed in sqlite3 when using the wrapper

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, wrapper

```
[sqlite executeQuery:@"UPDATE UserAccess SET Answer ='Positano';"];
NSArray *query2 = [sqlite executeQuery:@"SELECT Answer FROM UserAccess;"]; 
NSDictionary *dict = [query2 objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *itemValue = [dict objectForKey:@"Answer"]; 
NSLog(@"%@",itemValue);
```

It does print Positano at this point .. 
But when I just print without the update query again . I get the old entry which is Paris. 
I tried [sqlite commit];
which also doesn't work.
Even if I create a simple table it executes the first time then again when I hit the create button it says that the table already exists BUT when I rerun again it creates the table again instead of giving me an error that the table already exists .

What am I doing wrong ???
I am using  http://th30z.netsons.org/2008/11/objective-c-sqlite-wrapper/ 
wrapper.

Regards ,
Novice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded 
{
    // Testing for existence
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success) return;
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSAssert1(0,@"Failed to create writable database file with Message : '%@'.",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

In xxxxAppdelegate.m

That was the solution

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you didn't commit the transaction.

In the file Sqlite.m, there are methods beginTransaction and commit. Or you may try to set the db to the autocommit mode.

Comment: @Krab .. would you please give me an example . I am sorry .. I am new to Objective C